how to understand the grammatical construct of this sentence

どうやら、建物が、新しいとか、古いとかいう、見たところで、「ボロ」か、どうか決めるんだけど、やはり大切なのは、「入ってみたら……」のところで、子供とはいっても、学校は、建物より、内容で、「入ってみたら、いい学校！」のほうが、「いい」という真実をついてるところも、この歌には、あった。

what baffle me are:

how で in のところで functions? does it function as a place indicator as で in 学校で勉強する or as TE-form of だ in 僕は学生で、数学を勉強しています

how does で in 建物より、内容で function?

what part of this paragraph belongs to the content of 真実? does it conclude the whole part of 子供とはいっても、学校は、建物より、内容で、「入ってみたら、いい学校！」のほうが、「いい」?



The quote is apparently from 窓際のトットちゃん.



how で in のところで functions? does it function as a place indicator as で in 学校で勉強する or as TE-form of だ in 僕は学生で、数学を勉強しています


It's the latter.


how does で in 建物より、内容で function?


It's also the latter. I would parse the sentence like this:
｛どうやら、建物が、新しいとか、古いとかいう、見たところで、「ボロ」か、どうか決めるのだ｝
Rough translation: It seems that they judge a school by its appearance, like whether its building is new or old.
＋｛だけど、やはり大切なのは、「入ってみたら……」のところだ｝
But, what really matters is what happens once you actually enter the school.
＋｛子供とはいっても、学校は、建物より、内容だ｝
Even though they are just kids, their school's worth is the content (of its education), rather than its building.
＋｛「入ってみたら、いい学校！」のほうが、「いい」｝
A school that proves to be a good one after you enter is the better school (than a school with just a new building).
という真実をついてるところも、この歌には、あった。


what part of this paragraph belongs to the content of 真実? does it conclude the whole part of 子供とはいっても、学校は、建物より、内容で、「入ってみたら、いい学校！」のほうが、「いい」?


I think the 真実 refers to...
『やはり大切なのは、「入ってみたら……」のところで、
子供とはいっても、学校は、建物より、内容で、
「入ってみたら、いい学校！」のほうが、「いい」。』
...という真実。

I am not sure if it is correct that you separate 子供とはいっても、学校は、建物より、内容だ} and 「入ってみたら、いい学校！」のほうが、「いい」} as two clauses, because I usually see "AよりB ほうがいい" as a pattern.

What do you think the subject of this sentence やはり大切なのは、「入ってみたら……」のところで、子供とはいっても、学校は、建物より、内容で、「入ってみたら、いい学校！」のほうが、「いい」 is?

１文目は、「大切なのは」が主語で、「『入ってみたら』のところだ。」が述部です。２文目は、「学校は」が主語で、「建物より内容だ」が述部です。３文目は、「『入ってみたら、いい学校！』のほう」が主語で、「いい」が述部です。３文目は、『入学してみたらいい学校だと分かる学校のほうが 、建物が新しいだけの学校よりも 、いい学校だ。』って意味です。

「学校は、建物より内容(だ)。」 <-- 「[something] は、[element A] より [element B] (だ)。」 is a common structure that we often use to indicate which of the two elements in something is more crucial. Here are some common phrases with this structure: 「女は、器量より愛嬌。」「人は、外見より中身だ。」「勉強は量より質(だ)。」

thank you,you expain very well
